# error my getting tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "frame" command: application has been destroye

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *
Import random

Import time

Root=Tk ()
Root. geometry ("1600x800+0+0")
Root. title ("Resaurant Management System")


Tops = Frame(root, width=1600 ,bg="powder blue",relief=SUNKEN)
Tops.pack(side=TOP)

f1 = Frame(root, width=800,height=700 ,bg="powder blue",relief=SUNKEN)
f1.pack(side=LEFT)

f2 = Frame(root, width=300,height=700 ,bg="powder blue",relief=SUNKEN)
f2.pack(side=RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ersur/Downloads/restorent_mang_sy.py", line 11, in <module>
    Tops.pack(side=TOP)
  File "C:\Users\ersur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2738, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "C:\Users\ersur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2293, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "frame" command: application has been destroyed
```

Comment: Whats your question? Please format your code to make it more readable

Comment: I've formatted your code and error (to make it understandable)

Comment: This code can't possibly give the error you say it does, because the code won't execute due to incorrect import statements, and other errors.

Answer (score 0):

The capital "I" in "Import" creates a syntax error. Change it with "import".

In Tops, f1 and f2, change "root" with "Root" since, "root" is not defined